# put data from jtextfields into arraylist on JButton click (Actionlistener)

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, actionlistener, jtextfield

Sorry if my explanation of my problem is a bit clumsy.

Well, I'm trying to add X amount of JTextFields and add the content (int) of each of these into an arrayList. I want to send the arraylist with this information on click of my submit button.

So here is the loop, which creates the JTextFields and was supposed to add data from the fields to the arraylist.

```
If I enter antalVare = new JTextField("0"),
the 0 will be added to the arraylist,
```

but it should fill up the arraylist with the data from the JTextFields again on click of my JButton. How can i do this? I tried different ways using a Thread but failed.

```
    kundeOrdreArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    alleVarerList = kaldSQL.alleVarer(connectDB);

    try {
        while (alleVarerList.next()) {
            antalVare = new JTextField();

            innerPanel.add(new JLabel(alleVarerList.getString(2) + " ("
                    + alleVarerList.getString(3) + ",- kr.)"));
            innerPanel.add(antalVare);
            innerPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
            kundeOrdreArrayList.add(antalVare.getText());
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    innerPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    innerPanel.add(submit);
    innerPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
```

**And here's my ActionListener:**

```
if (a.getSource().equals(submit)) {
        // DO SOMETHING ?


            }
```

Comment: It is not obvious to me how these two snippets of code are related. I guess, the second one is the code which is executed once your JButton is clicked? Where is the second block of code and when is it executed? From your question I guess that you would need to call this piece of code from your ActionListener. Please make more clear, how these blocks of code are related.

Comment: The first snippet of code is runned when the class is executed. And yes the second snippet of code is runned when the 'submit' button is clicked. I cleard the ActionListener cus none of it was working.

Comment: Wrong code in the question is not necessarily a bad thing. It shows people what you tried and might help them to identify the issue. When writing my answer, I actually looked up the previous version and saw that you were just outputting the values which you had computed when "the class is executed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first snippet of code, you the values you add to `kundeOrdreArrayList` are the values of the text fields have *at this time*. These value is not updated when the text fields are changed afterwards.

So, in your ActionListener, you need to iterate again over all your JTextFields. To do this, first change your first snippet of code to keep track of all the JTextFields you have. So,
add a new field "ArrayList textfields" to your class, then (marked the changed lines with `// ++`

```
textfields = new ArrayList<JTextField>(); // ++

try {
    while (alleVarerList.next()) {
        antalVare = new JTextField();
        textfields.add(antalVare); // ++

        innerPanel.add(new JLabel(alleVarerList.getString(2) + " ("
                + alleVarerList.getString(3) + ",- kr.)"));
        innerPanel.add(antalVare);
        innerPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
        kundeOrdreArrayList.add(antalVare.getText());
    }
```

Now, in your ActionListener, clear kundeOrdreArrayList and add the values from all the JTextFields again:

```
  if (a.getSource().equals(submit)) {
      kundeOrdreArrayList.clear();
      for (JTextField field : textfields) {
           kundeOrdreArrayList.add(field.getText());
      }
  }
```